# CSS Sizing problems (basic)

Tags: html, css, webkit

I've been trying to make a website like [this](http://www.spookycraft.net/). Though from my understanding that website is in Jquery and I only want to work in HTML and CSS, so I used some webkit animations. However they have a small space between the top and the photo sliding up. I have no idea how to fix it. If anyone could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Here's the website: http://www.wandernetwork.com/

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8QhKW/

and here's the raw code:

```
 <! DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title> Wandercraft Network </title>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">

#page-wrap{
    width:620px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.slide-up-boxes a {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background: #eee;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slide-up-boxes h5 {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:150px;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.3s linear;
    background-color:#white;
}
.slide-up-boxes a:hover h5 {
    margin-top:-300px;
}
.slide-up-boxes div {
    text-align:center;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    opacity:0;
    background-color:orange;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.slide-up-boxes a:hover div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    opacity:1;
}

.slide-up-boxes {
 margin:5px;
 width:300px;
 float:left;
}

.banner{
margin:0px auto;
display:block;
padding:15px;
width:1000px;
height:300px;
}

/* =====================================================================*/
/*  MAKES THE ENJIN TRAY RUN VERTICALLY RATHER THAN HORIZONTALLY
/* =====================================================================*/

/* Limit the width of the tray to 30px to make it stack vertically*/

#enjin-tray {
    max-width: 30px;
    margin: 0;

/*adjust to your desired distance from the bottom of the window*/   

    bottom: 175px;

}

/*Make all of the corners rounded*/
#enjin-tray li#notificationpanel { border-radius: 3px;}

/* make the border cover all edges */
#enjin-tray ul li.tray-item {border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;}

/* Edit the alignment of the background images */
#notificationpanel .notification-icon.apps {background-position: -84px 3px;}
#notificationpanel .notification-icon.general {background-position: -54px 3px;}
#notificationpanel .notification-icon.messages {background-position: -25px 3px;}

/*Hide the Home button - it's redundant and it's wider than the others, so it looks funny stacked vertically */
#notificationpanel .notification-icon.dashboard {display: none;}

/*Subpanel Tweaks - for the pop-up panel  -- bottom: 0 will line the panel up with the bottom of the tray*/
#enjin-tray li#notificationpanel .subpanel {width: 380px; bottom: 0;}

/*fixe the horizontal alignment for the different panels*/
#enjin-tray #notificationpanel .subpanel.general {right: 40px;}
#enjin-tray #notificationpanel .subpanel.messages {right: 40px;}
#enjin-tray .subpanel {right: 40px;}

/*Hide the fake icons that appear when the subpanel opens */
#enjin-tray #notificationpanel .subpanel.apps .faux-icon {display: none;}
#enjin-tray #notificationpanel .subpanel.general .faux-icon {display: none;}
#enjin-tray #notificationpanel .subpanel.messages .faux-icon {display: none;}


/*Move notification tip - the "right: 35px" pulls the tips to the left of the tray. The "bottom: 231px" will have to be adjusted 
according to how high up the side of the browser window you placed your tray in the #enjin-tray section */

#messages-notification-tip {bottom: 231px !important; right: 35px !important;}
#general-notification-tip {bottom: 205px !important; right: 35px !important;}
#apps-notification-tip {bottom: 180px !important; right: 35px !important;}

/*Hide the little chat tail on the notification pop-up */
   .triangle {display: none;}

/*move the one-on-one chat icon over to the right edge of the page, now that the tray is out of the way (if you're beta-testing the chat */
   #enjin-tray-messaging {display: none;}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/WN_Banner.png" border="0px" class="banner">

    <div id="page-wrap">
        <section class="slide-up-boxes">
            <a href="www.reddit.com">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/PVP.png">
        <div> 
        <h5> <img src="http://www.backbonetechnology.com/media/blog-html5-logo.png"> </h5>
         </div>
        </a>
        </section>

    <section class="slide-up-boxes">
        <a href="www.reddit.com">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/Kingdoms.png">
        <div> 
        <h5> <img src="http://www.backbonetechnology.com/media/blog-html5-logo.png"> </h5>
         </div>
        </a>
    </section>

        <section class="slide-up-boxes">
        <a href="www.reddit.com">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/Survival.png">
        <div> 
        <h5> <img src="http://www.backbonetechnology.com/media/blog-html5-logo.png"> </h5>
         </div>
        </a>
        </section>
            <section class="slide-up-boxes">
            <a href="www.reddit.com">
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/Factions.png">
            <div> 
            <h5> <img src="http://www.backbonetechnology.com/media/blog-html5-logo.png"> </h5>
             </div>
            </a>
        </section>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for reading, Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand, what is the point?

Comment: please explain what you want to do exactly, what is the final result that you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, It probably wasn't very obvious but I wanted the boxes to not have a space between the top border and the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.slide-up-boxes a {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

The thing is `a` elements will take up the height from the line-height property even when they don't have a text node, since you are working with images, you don't want to add any height to it

Comment: Whoa! This one worked like a charm thank you for taking the time to answer and explain it to me, I really appreciate it, ALL HAIL THE MIGHTY AND ALL KNOWING KOALA_DEV!

Answer (score 1):

You could change your change of margin from

```
.slide-up-boxes a:hover h5 {
    margin-top:-300px;
}
```

to

```
.slide-up-boxes a:hover h5 {
    margin-top:-305px;
}
```

Or find where that extra margin is coming from ;)

Comment: When I open this in chrome it added the bored to the bottom rather than the top and previously on chrome it was fine, Tho the website didn't have the space when I ran it in chrome and it does when I apply it to enjinn or use it on Jsfiddle so i'm going to try it, Thank you for your answer, I'll mark it as correct if it works.

Comment: I tried it in the element inspector in chrome, and it did the trick

Comment: Nevermind, The all knowing Koala_Dev had a fix for me and the reason I was having a problem was the A elements will take up the height of the line-height property even when they don't have a text node, since I was working with images, you don't want to add any height to it.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can eliminate this problem by adding following code:

```
div#page-wrap section.slide-up-boxes a div {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

But sure, making the line-height to 0 of a tags will be better ;)